# Magento 1.9.3 Order delivery address change history?

Tags: sales-order, magento1.9.3

When I have edited the delivery address for an order. Can I see what was the delivery address before I made the change again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the old address for that order will not be saved, however if the customer had the address in an old order you could possibly find it there.